# Using select() then read() vs a blocking read() loop

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am working on a multi-threaded server code where I create 2 threads which interact with a blocking TCP Socket after `accept()`.

Thread #1 checks to see if there is a commands from msg queue and writes it to the socket. Thread #2 is just a simple while loop that calls `read` and then blocks if there is no data ready to be read.

However my colleague told me that I should not do a while loop with a `read` as it will waste CPU cycles (It's a blocking `read`, doesn't kernel put the thread to sleep?), that I should use `select()` system call then read the socket.

Am I incorrect with assuming the read thread? Which approach is better?

Comment: What os used? Ofcourse - you can use select/poll/epoll. For example: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzab6/poll.htm

Comment: It's a pure Linux program, SLES11 to be exact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that a thread does not consume CPU while blocked on I/O.

The `select()` syscall is a viable alternative, but its main use case is multiplexing I/O from / to multiple channels.  In that case, it's not viable for one thread serve all the channels via blocking reads (or writes) because it would frequently be blocked waiting for data from one channel while a different one had data ready and waiting.  On the other hand, you don't want to perform *non-blocking* reads in a loop, as that **will** waste CPU.

As for whether to prefer blocking on `read()` or blocking on `select()` (or `poll()`) for managing a single channel, that's a bit of an apples-to-oranges comparison, but if those are the choices then it's more straightforward to block on `read()`.  That's what I would do.  The apples-to-apples comparison would be more along the lines of multiple threads or child processes, each blocking on `read()`ing a different channel, vs. one thread of one process managing multiple channels with the help of `select()`.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple read() also be faster compared to doing two system calls with select() then read also?

Comment: @hastartes, marginally faster, yes, but you'd not likely notice the difference.  Performance in a situation like this is sure to be bound by the actual data transfer.

Answer (score -3):

Looping around to see if there is data is not a good way of doing it as your friend suggested. It wastes CPU time. This method is called polling, which is an inefficient way of doing this

Instead , Read should be event driven. Which means the Read thread will not be running at all until there is data available to read. 
So, what your friend suggested is correct. You should move to event driven model. What this so called Select() call does is, it tells the TCP stack to inform the read thread, when ever there is data available.

so instead of your thread checking whether data is available continuously, TCP will let you know when there is data for you.

Hope its clear

Comment: A read loop does not consume CPU while blocked on I/O.  Polling does waste CPU, but no polling is being performed by the program the OP describes; that would be what you get with *non-blocking* reads.

Comment: Isn't `select()` also a form of polling?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann, no select() is not a form of polling, at least not these days. In the late 80s and early 1990s some Unixes implemented select() as a polling loop because they didn't have the right underlying driver architecture to support a proper blocking mechanism. The implementation of select() on Cygwin also polls (it sets up a thread per file descriptor each of which polls for data being available), or at least it used to do that.